# op amp level shift circuit diagram?

Tags: operational-amplifier, level-shifting

Can someone please help me with explaining the op amp level shift functioning with circuit diagram?
Thank you

Comment: Naivete can sometimes be beautiful but right now I'm not so sure. Op-amps can shift levels for sure but there could be up to a dozen different circuits that could apply to this question.

Comment: If this is about a particular cicuit, show the circuit.  If this is actually asking how a opamp can be used to level-shift, then ask that.  As it stands this question is either lacking context or very poorly written.

Answer (score 3):

I used this circuit several times and it works for me.

Although you should add a little more information to your question. What kind of signal needs to be shifted? What is it's initial voltage? How much does it need to shift up or down? Things like that.

[image: IMG]
<sub>(source: [daycounter.com](http://www.daycounter.com/Circuits/OpAmp-Level-Shifter/OpAmp-Level-Shifter.gif))</sub>

The according formulas can be found here: http://www.daycounter.com/Circuits/OpAmp-Level-Shifter/OpAmp-Level-Shifter.phtml

As reference voltage I used a simple voltage divider consisting of 2 resistors.